# How pointer to member struct work?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am beginner in c++ and I want to question about how pointer to member struct work. Here I have code:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;     // next variable store address of Node.

    void Print()
    {
        cout <<"Value in next variable is: " <<&next;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node Sample;
    sample.data = 5;
    cout <<"Data is: " <<sample.data <<"\n";
    sample.Print();
    cout <<"Address of Sample is: " <<&Sample <<"\n";
}
```

Output:

Data is: 5

Value in next variable is: 0xbf9b6758

Address of Sample is: 0xbf9b6754

In this case pointer variable `next` has different address with `&Sample`. How this work? Why they have different address?

Comment: and how the `next` is supposed to be "holding" or "pointing to" anything?

Comment: How could they have the same address?

Comment: please fix typos, this code wont compile

Comment: @SouravGhosh next = &sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to query:**

```
Value in next variable is: 0xbf9b6758 
Address of Sample is: 0xbf9b6754
```

These 4 steps  learn you what is happening arround?

**step 1:** firstly, structure var sample is declared.

**step 2:** As sample is created into memory ,members of sample is initialized with default values.

**step 3:** becoz next is a pointer variable so, it will also initialized with some garbage value( i.e. next unused address in Ram).

**step 4:** next pointer holds the address -`0xbf9b6758` because,

*"size of sample variable is = sum of sizes of each member of struct node"*

= size of data + size of next

= 2 + 2 => 4

**KeyPoint -->** Size  of next is 2 byte because  Addresses in memory are of unsigned integer format(datatype)

So, next variable is assigned the different address from sample variable.

Comment: I hope you can understand the whole concept.

Comment: one thing is important for you as beginner that next pointer always points to the next node in the linked-list by assignining the ,  next=&next_node

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very usefull.

Comment: it's my pleasure.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the value of next. You take the address of next (by printing `&next`). The address of the member next is the address is simply `((char *)&Sample) + offsetof(Node, next)`. I.e. the address of Sample plus the position of the member relative to the start of the struct.

The value of next could be printed by leaving out the `&` operator: `cout << next`, however you never set the value of `next` to begin with, so its value will be arbitrary.

Comment: imho an answer should at least mention that what op is printing is not the "value of next" but its address